# Get "Response code = 500" error randomly when running cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

For some reason I keep getting a response code of 500 when I run cucumber, even though all the tests pass. The error occurs randomly for different tests, every time I run it. Sometimes all tests pass as well.

I thought it was a memory issue, so I tried restarting my computer, but that didn't do anything.

An example of the error is:

```
And I follow "link"                                                       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
  Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error. (ActiveResource::ServerError)
  ./app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:23:in `show'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
  features/manage_sites.feature:256:in `And I follow "link"'
```

It seems related to the tagging feature. I was using the @wip tag, and when I moved it around, it would cause the sporadic 500 errors. Removing all @wip tags makes all the tests pass.

I could be wrong though. I'll need to try and replicate it consistently.

Would anybody be able to help?

Comment: Are there any pointers in the log file?